# How to remove border on element?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, capacitor

I used `Dropdown` from `react-bootstrap`

code is look like this

```
<Dropdown className="my-dropdown p-0 m-0">
<Dropdown.Toggle className="p-0 m-0" split={false} variant="light-dropdown">
<Image src="/more@3x.png" style={{ height: '22px' }} />
</Dropdown.Toggle>
....
```

When I click on it it shows a light blue coloured outline around the image
I don't know why it is there.

Not only for this element but I am facing same for `Button` as well.

```
<Button
variant="footer">
```

Please help to fix this.

[image]

Comment: * { outline: none !important; } in your css file

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an outline appearing when you click on your button.
Try this in your css on your button :

```
.button:focus,.button:active {
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: It's due to focus, I think.

Comment: This is bad practice for accessibility.